# Redirect or rewrite from www.somedomain.com to www.somedomain.com/en/ in IIS

Tags: iis

This is what I would like to achieve:

1. A user surfs to www.somedomain.com
2. IIS rewrites the url/redirects to www.somedomain.com/en/

How to create such a rule in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Open IIS Manager and navigate to the level you want to manage.

In Features View, double-click HTTP Redirect.

On the HTTP Redirect page, select Redirect requests to this destination.

In the corresponding box, type the file name, directory path, or URL to which you want to redirect the user.

In the Actions pane, click Apply.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732930(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Getting "This webpage has a redirect loop" in Chrome.

Comment: Your website is probably set up to the domain www.somedomain.com. Check it's code/config/settings. It should be set to www.somedomain.com/en or it will keep trying to go to the original domain and get forwarded and repeat in a loop.